# Duplicates in hadoop mapreduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, duplicates

I'm starting out with hadoop 0.20.2. I wanted to start out with the basic wordcount problem with the code I found here:
http://cxwangyi.blogspot.com/2009/12/wordcount-tutorial-for-hadoop-0201.html

This works like it should.
However, when the words are seperated over multiple files and I want to count words per file, so I change the mapper to:

```
String fileName = ((org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileSplit) context.getInputSplit()).getPath().getName();

            word.set(itr.nextToken()+"@"+fileName);
```

But then I get duplicates in my mapreduced file, like this:
word1@file1 1
word2@file2 1
word2@file2~    1
...

So word2@file2~ 1 should not have been there...

Anybody knows what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like your text editor is auto-saving files. For example, emacs often creates auto saves with a ``~`` in front of the file name. In that case you would end up with ``file2`` and ``file2~``.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you don't have a file with the tilde at the end added to the input for the hadoop job? Some editors like Gedit generate them every time the file gets edited.

Comment: Oh, of course. 
Stupid me was already exploring the core of hadoop all day.
Thanks!